# Autodesk Maya debugging with Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, maya

I was trying to debug my own plugins for Maya in Visual Studio Code, but i can't get it! I got the Script Editor connected with the VSCode console, but the code, never stop at the code.

Someone also tried this and get it??

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Use "Attach to process" in Visual Studio and select "Maya.exe"

Comment: That option is not available in Visual Studio Code :(

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the python tag before.  You could try this:https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Comment: You'd probably need to tell the IDE (Visual Studio) where to find maya and the python it is running.

Comment: I tried with the Python Extension, but when i configure the launch.json, the debugger didnt reach the breakpoints. Im also using the maya python interpreter (mayapy). I think it should be something in the launch.json, but i cant figure out what it is :(